# SonarQube report not updated

Tags: sonarqube

I just installed SonarQube on a localhost virtual machine using docker. I can access the admin interface using http://192.168.xx.xx:9000

I create a new project and run the sonar-scanner on my local machine (this one can obviously access my virtual machine) using the following command :

```
/opt/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006-linux/bin/sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=Open-Capture-NCH01 \
  -Dsonar.sources=. \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.xx.xx:9000 \
  -Dsonar.token=sqp_xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have no issue while running it, but the SonarQube interface is not updated and stay in this state :

[image]

Here is the log of the sonar-scanner, I didn't see any errors and didn't understand why I can't get a report on SonarQube :

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006-linux/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /var/www/html/opencapture/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarScanner 5.0.1.3006
INFO: Java 17.0.7 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 6.5.0-15-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/nathan/.sonar/cache
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 10.3.0.82913
INFO: Default locale: "fr_FR", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=81ms
INFO: Server id: 147B411E-AY01gDxStIkAhcWdfspb
INFO: User cache: /home/nathan/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=41ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=95ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=8ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Project key: Open-Capture-NCH01
INFO: Base dir: /var/www/html/opencapture
INFO: Working dir: /var/www/html/opencapture/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'Open-Capture-NCH01'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'Open-Capture-NCH01' (done) | time=59ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=163ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=8151ms
INFO: Load analysis cache
INFO: Load analysis cache (404) | time=28ms
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=28ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
WARN: Not indexing due to symlink loop: /var/www/html/opencapture/test
WARN: Not indexing due to symlink loop: /var/www/html/opencapture/edissyum
INFO: 838 files indexed
INFO: 44050 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for css: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for json: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for php: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for ts: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for web: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module Open-Capture-NCH01
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=47ms
INFO: Sensor Python Sensor [python]
WARN: Your code is analyzed as compatible with all Python 3 versions by default. You can get a more precise analysis by setting the exact Python version in your configuration via the parameter "sonar.python.version"
INFO: Starting global symbols computation
INFO: 137 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 137/137 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Starting rules execution
INFO: 137 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 137/137 source files have been analyzed
INFO: The Python analyzer was able to leverage cached data from previous analyses for 0 out of 137 files. These files were not parsed.
INFO: Sensor Python Sensor [python] (done) | time=6378ms
INFO: Sensor Cobertura Sensor for Python coverage [python]
INFO: Sensor Cobertura Sensor for Python coverage [python] (done) | time=165ms
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python]
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python] (done) | time=157ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor IaC CloudFormation Sensor [iac]
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor IaC CloudFormation Sensor [iac] (done) | time=28ms
INFO: Sensor IaC AzureResourceManager Sensor [iac]
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor IaC AzureResourceManager Sensor [iac] (done) | time=33ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript/TypeScript analysis [javascript]
INFO: Detected os: Linux arch: amd64 alpine: false. Platform: LINUX_X64
INFO: Using Node.js executable: 'node'.
INFO: Memory configuration: OS (63977 MB), Node.js (4144 MB).
```

Thanks for your help